# Data frame specific row value selection

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with multiple column. One of the column-ID value as look like INSMO* and this will be varying. "INS" is constant. How do i check INS* present in the column or not[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your case just do

```
out = df[df['col'].str[:3].eq('INS')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do `startswith`:

```
out = df[df['col'].str.startswith('INS')]
```

Or:

```
out = df[df.iloc[:, 1].str.startswith('INS')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
has_it = df['whatever the second column is named'].str.contains(r'^INS', regex=True)
```